# Autoincrement value

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, auto-increment

I'm working on a local project and I would like to setup a column in a SQL Server table that I called `serial`. This value should have the next format/validation `[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]`. Four characters that will have numbers or capital letters.

For example, the first record would be `AAA0`, and then start incrementing from right to left, but the interesting part is that once it reaches `AAA9`, I want to continue but with letters, so once 9 is reached, continue with A: `AAAA`. My last combination would be `AAAZ`, and then continue with the second position and so on, until I could complete `ZZZZ`.

```
Serial
------
AAA0
…
AAAZ
AAB0
…
AABZ
AAC0
…
AACZ
…
ZZZZ
```

I've been able to do something similar, but for example only incrementing numbers 0000 until 9999 or with just letters AAAA to ZZZZ (see below dummy data).

[image]

Please let me know if you have any comments or if you have seen this scenario before. I will appreciate any help.

I've reviewed some data on the internet and did this small test, but once again, this is changing letters.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    MyHeadID INT IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    Consecutive AS 
            CHAR(MyHeadID/17576%26+65) +        --26^3
            CHAR(MyHeadID/676%26+65)  +         --26^2
            CHAR(MyHeadID/26%26+65)  +          --26^1
            CHAR(MyHeadID%26+65)                --26^0
                PERSISTED  NOT NULL,
    UniqueID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate datetime DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

 INSERT INTO #MyTable (UniqueID) 
    (SELECT NEWID())

 SELECT Consecutive FROM #MyTable
```

Let's not talk about the `UniqueID` and `CreatedDate` columns, those are just for testing purposes. I created an identity column and then the code for the autoincrement on letters.

I also found this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27224493/4459694) here but it's not my case since in that reply they are dividing 4 letters and 4 numbers with a substring it can be resolved. In my case, I need to intercalculate numbers and letters from right to left.

Comment: Just use a normal IDENTITY column and look for a function that does base 36 encoding to present that in your desired format

Comment: Thanks for the recomendations @Dale K. I haven't try anything because I don't know if this is even possible. I haven't found anything yet here on stack as well. -MG

Comment: @MoisesGonzaga use https://dbfiddle.uk/ for create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @Marco Aurelio, I have shared some code that I have and that helped me start this 'idea' of serial number.

Comment: Confused about the "numbering" after the rightmost column reaches Z are you expecting `AAB0` then `AAB1 AAB2... AABZ, AAC0 etc`?

Comment: That's right, @stu, after the rightmost column reaches Z, I would expect to move the next letter and then start at 0. AAA0,AAA1,AAA2,AAA3,AAA4...AAA9,AAAA, AAAB...AAAZ,AAB0,AAB1,AAB2..AABZ, AAC0, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, counting in base 36 AAA0 starts at decimial 479879.

Ideally you'd have an identity incrementing number on your table starting at 479879. Simulating that with a numbers table generated using a CTE, the following gives base36 counting:

```
with numbers as (
    select 479879 + Row_Number() over (order by a.object_id)n 
    from sys.all_objects a cross join sys.all_objects b
)
select top 10000
    Concat(Char(((n/36/36/36) % 36) + case when (n/36/36/36) % 36 between 0 and 9 then 48 else 55 end),
    Char(((n/36/36) % 36) + case when (n/36/36) % 36 between 0 and 9 then 48 else 55 end),
    Char(((n/36) % 36) + case when (n/36) % 36 between 0 and 9 then 48 else 55 end),
    Char((n % 36) + case when n % 36 between 0 and 9 then 48 else 55 end)) Base36
from numbers 
order by n
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e6d385c6d409bb70fba39709c2e71c6)

Comment: Thank you Stu, this is basically what I'm trying to accomplish based on my description.

Comment: Excellent - sounds like you might be needing to tweak maybe but hopefully gets you where you need to be.

Comment: Yeap! I have modied a little bit in order to have it complete for my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is good but you can do this and cover all numbers with simple math. Also, let's assume your `IDENTITY` starts at one. There are 36 values for each digit, so those are base 36 encoded as pointed out. The encoding goes 0 - 9 then A - Z as you mentioned in your post.  The get the individual digits of some number `n` from right to left, the algorithm goes:

1. `n mod 36` is the right most digit.
2. `n / 36 mod 36` gives the second-to-right digit.
3. `n / (36 * 36) mod 36` gives the second-to-left digit.
4. `n / (36 * 36 * 36) mod 36` gives left digit.

To test this logic, we can write a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CustomNumber(@id INT)
RETURNS CHAR(4)
AS BEGIN
    RETURN CHAR((@id-1)/ POWER(36, 3)% 36+CASE WHEN (@id-1)/ POWER(36, 3)% 36 BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END) 
    +CHAR((@id-1)/ POWER(36, 2)% 36+CASE WHEN (@id-1)/ POWER(36, 2)% 36 BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END)
    +CHAR((@id-1)/ 36% 36+CASE WHEN (@id-1)/ 36% 36 BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END)
    +CHAR((@id-1)% 36+CASE WHEN (@id-1)% 36 BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END);
END;
```

We can then test this function by calling it to make sure it works. To call it, lets create some numbers. This is complete overkill, but let's pass it 1 through 1,000,000 so we can see it in action:

```
;WITH digits (I)
AS ( 
   SELECT I 
   FROM (VALUES (0), (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS digits (I) ),
integers (I)
AS (SELECT D1.I + (10 * D2.I) + (100 * D3.I) + (1000 * D4.I) + (10000*D5.I) + (100000*D6.I)
    FROM digits AS D1
        CROSS JOIN digits AS D2
        CROSS JOIN digits AS D3
        CROSS JOIN digits AS D4
        CROSS JOIN digits AS D5 CROSS JOIN digits AS D6
      )
SELECT I, dbo.CustomNumber(I)
FROM integers 
WHERE I > 0
ORDER BY I;
```

If you run that and patiently wait (it takes about 20 seconds on my weak laptop, but you don't have to use a million numbers if you don't like) you will see that it does produce the result that you want. At this point we know the formula is correct, so you have options to add it to your table.

One option is to use the formula as a `PERSISTED` column as you did. Another option is to use a trigger. You can leave the formula as a function or you can just put the code in directly. If you need more characters than 4, you can easily add another by following the pattern (just change the `POWER` to which you raise).

As I mentioned, the previous answer is good, I just wanted to show another method and its derivation. I have had to implement custom sequences several times with varying formats and you can use this general technique.